# this table cannot be shown because it is not in import mode

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, powerquery, pgadmin

I've connected my powerbi for direct flow of the data with pgadmin which directly get the data from the aws. But I can't view my tables which I selected in the table view section. It shows as "this table cannot be shown because it is not in import mode". I tried checking with the settings and it is all fine but don't know how to proceed further.
[image]

I tried connecting again with the pgadmin and still getting the same issue.

Comment: This is normal behaviour for Direct Query tables (not Imported).